# Check the unique values of 2 character variables match using set_equal in R

Tags: r, dplyr, sapply

I have 2 data tables with about ~500k obs. and ~50 variables. Some of these variables contain characters and I would like to find a simple, quick way of checking the unique values of each character variable in one data table matches (or doesn't) the corresponding variable in the second data table

I assumed that using `sapply` and `set_equal` would give me my answer, but it always returns FALSE for each variable, even when I know the answer should be TRUE. Testing an individual pair of variables, returns the correct answer. I could loop over each pair of variables, and this works, but I'm trying to understand why my `sapply`/`set_equal` method doesn't and fix it so it does (or find an alternative non-looping method).

```
> # Extract & sort unique values from character vars in cube1 for matching character vars
> cube1c <- sapply(cube1m[, ..commonCharCols], unique)
> cube1c <- sapply(cube1c, sort)

> # Extract & sort unique values from character vars in cube2 for matching character vars
> cube2c <- sapply(cube2m[, ..commonCharCols], unique)
> cube2c <- sapply(cube2c, sort)

> # Test if values in each pair of variables are the same
> sapply(cube1c, function(x) setequal(x, cube2c)) 
cVar1 cVar2 cVar3 cVar4 cVar5 cVar6
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> setequal(cube1c$cVar2, cube2c$cVar2)
[1] TRUE

> for (icol in seq_len(length(commonCharCols))) {
+     print(commonCharCols[[icol]])
+     print(setequal(cube1c[[icol]], cube2c[[icol]]))
+ }
[1] "cVar1"
[1] FALSE
[1] "cVar2"
[1] TRUE
[1] "cVar3"
[1] FALSE
[1] "cVar4"
[1] TRUE
[1] "cVar5"
[1] TRUE
[1] "cVar6"
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `mapply` for elementwise loop of equal length objects to call `setequal`:

```
output <- mapply(setequal, cube1c, cube2c)
```

---

To demonstrate with random, seeded data

**Data**

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(872019)
data_tools <- c("sas", "stata", "spss", "python", "r", "julia")
cube1m <- data.table(replicate(50, sample(data_tools, 10, replace=TRUE)))

head(cube1m)    
#       V1     V2     V3    V4     V5
# 1:     r python   spss julia    sas
# 2: julia   spss python julia python
# 3: stata      r    sas stata      r
# 4:     r      r  julia julia    sas
# 5: julia      r    sas  spss      r
# 6: stata      r      r     r    sas

cube2m <- data.table(replicate(50, sample(data_tools, 10, replace=TRUE)))

head(cube2m)
#        V1    V2     V3     V4    V5
# 1:    sas  spss python      r stata
# 2:      r  spss  julia    sas     r
# 3:  julia julia  stata python julia
# 4:      r     r   spss  stata julia
# 5:  julia     r  stata python   sas
# 6: python     r  stata    sas stata
```

**Code + Output**

```
commonCharCols <- paste0("V", 1:50)
cube1c <- sapply(cube1m[, ..commonCharCols], function(x) sort(unique(x)))        
cube2c <- sapply(cube2m[, ..commonCharCols], function(x) sort(unique(x)))

output <- mapply(setequal, cube1c, cube2c)

output
#    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12   V13   V14   V15 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE 
#   V16   V17   V18   V19   V20   V21   V22   V23   V24   V25   V26   V27   V28   V29   V30 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
#   V31   V32   V33   V34   V35   V36   V37   V38   V39   V40   V41   V42   V43   V44   V45 
#  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
#   V46   V47   V48   V49   V50 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

 output[output == TRUE]
 #   V6  V13  V20  V21  V23  V31  V33  V39 
 # TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

**Check**

```
sharedCols <- names(output[output == TRUE])

cube1m[, ..sharedCols]    
#         V6    V13    V20    V21    V23    V31    V33    V39
#  1:   spss  julia      r   spss python python python   spss
#  2:    sas    sas    sas  stata   spss   spss  stata      r
#  3:    sas  julia      r      r python      r    sas  julia
#  4:   spss      r  julia   spss  stata      r  stata      r
#  5: python   spss  stata   spss      r  stata  stata  julia
#  6:    sas python      r  julia    sas  julia python python
#  7:      r python    sas python  stata  julia   spss   spss
#  8:    sas    sas python  stata      r python    sas  julia
#  9:  julia  stata      r   spss  julia      r python    sas
# 10:  stata  julia   spss    sas    sas   spss  julia    sas

cube2m[, ..sharedCols]    
#         V6    V13    V20    V21    V23    V31    V33    V39
#  1:  julia  julia      r  stata    sas   spss  stata  julia
#  2: python  julia  julia    sas python  julia python   spss
#  3:    sas  stata    sas  julia   spss python  stata  julia
#  4: python  stata    sas      r      r python    sas      r
#  5:   spss   spss    sas   spss   spss      r  julia python
#  6:  stata python   spss  julia      r  julia python   spss
#  7: python    sas python python  julia  julia  stata    sas
#  8:    sas      r      r    sas    sas  stata   spss   spss
#  9:  julia    sas  stata    sas  stata python python  julia
# 10:      r  stata  julia      r   spss      r  stata      r
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't consider `mapply`. This works exactly as I wanted :)

Comment: Great! Glad to help. You can also cut down on multiple `sapply` by extending first call: `sapply(cube1m[, ..commonCharCols], function(x) sort(unique(x)))`.